# Visual Studio 2017 makes ding noise and does nothing

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I upgraded VS from VS 2017 RC to VS 2017 and I have noticed that when I try to start it up that it just makes the Windows Ding sound and nothing happens.

Comment: I've got this problem right now in VS2022. I've no idea why. I just created a new WPF solution. It's happened a few times before. I had to use Task Manager to terminate Visual Studio. I noticed after restarting, that I was no longer signed in Visual Studio, so I wonder if it was an SSO dialog. My organisation uses SSO and forces a log out every 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would uninstall Visual Studio with the visual studio uninstaller on github and then reinstall.

Sounds like the upgrade did not work right

https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Comment: I'll try to run the uninstaller and reinstall it. I'll let you know how it goes.